# Texstudio PDF viewer centering in two columns

Tags: texstudio

Using `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`, I get a two column output but if I don't have two monitors, it is more comfortable to just set the width to one column. Unfortunately every time I select test from the editor it will not center appropriately on the column where the text is found.

I tried to compile for just one column to facilitate editing, but the largest font size is `\documentclass[journal,12pt,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}` which is not large enough to reflect the actual column width.

So I just want the PDF preview to be smart enough to center on a column when text is selected in the editor and the view width is set to column width.

Comment: Either this is a PDF viewer issue, or you shouldn't use IEEE tran in preview mode.  I would suggest writing out `\the\columnwidth` and `\the\textheight` and using the geometry package to create a page with one column with the exact same size.  (flowfram?)

Comment: \usepackage[text={4in,10in},centering]{geometry} is a a work around.  Still I think Texstudio should be smart enough on a editor text locate to recognize a smaller PDF viewer size and center on the column instead of the entire page width which requires panning when the text is not in the current column being viewed.

Comment: In fact for any number of columns texstudio should do its best to  position the PDF viewer to display the entire column width where the text is located.